# Passing a string value between two different android applications?

Tags: android, string, message-passing, android-bundle

Is it possible to be able to pass a string value between two different applications?

First app:

```
final Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
final String a = bundle.getString("data");

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("me.stuart.foodapp");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString(a, a);
i.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(i);
```

Second app:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String a = bundle.getString("data");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [send a broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29) with data from one application to another. Broadcasts are by their nature a cross-application facility